# homology of finitely generated group

Tags: homology-cohomology, group-cohomology, classifying-spaces

The homology groups of every finite group are finite and those of $\mathbb{Z}^n$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$ are finitely generated. I was wondering whether for some finitely generated group there is a homology group $H^n(G,\mathbb{Z})$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$ which is not finitely generated. This of course can not take place for any group $G$ whose classifying space is compact as the homology groups will be finitely generated in this case.

Comment: Do you mean $H_i$ is not finitely generated for some $i$ or $\bigoplus_{i\geq 0}H_i$ is not finitely generated?

Comment: I mean $H_i$ for some $i$.

Comment: Apparently examples were constructed by Stallings: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/177989/is-there-a-finitely-presented-group-with-infinite-homology-over-mathbbq